# Dynamically rename an XML File in Shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, dynamic, rename

I have an XML files named as *dmi_standard_load_B0001_set.xml* and I want to rename it dynamically by accepting a *batch_name* from user and change it to *dmi_standard_load_${batch_name}_set.xml*.

How can I do that ? I tried the following command bt it throws error and doesn't work...

```
 mv dmi_standard_load_*_set.xml dmi_standard_load_${batch_name}_set.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

So what is your typical batch name any spaces in it. If so you may need to put speech marks around the file name the 2nd bit. Worth echo $ batch_name aldo u could try load_$(echo $ $batch_name)_set.xml

Comment: my batch_name is like B0001.

Answer (score 1):

Careful! You are using a * wildcard in your command. If you have multiple XML files in your directory, for instance :

```
dmi_standard_load_B0001_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_B0002_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_B0003_set.xml
```

your command will expand to this :

```
mv dmi_standard_load_B0001_set.xml dmi_standard_load_B0002_set.xml dmi_standard_load_B0003_set.xml dmi_standard_load_${batch_name}_set.xml
```

and most likely, it will fail, telling you that the last argument is not a directory. So the first thing is, you want to loop through your files, like so :

```
for f in dmi_standard_load_*_set.xml
do
    mv ${f} dmi_standard_load_${batch_name}_set.xml
done
```

**DO NOT RUN THAT CODE THOUGH!** We're not finished. The problem here is that you're going to rename each of your XML files... to one and only one file. In effect, you'll end up with a file named `dmi_standard_load_${batch_name}_set.xml`, with the contents of the last XML file that went through the loop.

You want the user to give a different batch name for each of these files, right? So you need to ask her for each file in your loop, with the `read` command :

```
for f in dmi_standard_load_*_set.xml
do
    echo Please enter a batch name for file $f :
    read batch_name
    mv ${f} dmi_standard_load_${batch_name}_set.xml
done
```

This will work, but there is no error checking... the user could just press the Enter key, giving an empty batch name. Here's a final version that makes sure the user gives a name :

```
for f in dmi_standard_load_*_set.xml
do
    batch_name=
    while [[ ${batch_name} == '' ]]
    do
        echo Please enter a batch name for file $f :
        read batch_name
    done
    mv ${f} dmi_standard_load_${batch_name}_set.xml
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use this one-line script:

```
for file_name in *; do echo -ne "Renaming file \"${file_name}\" Enter batch_name: "; read batch_name; mv "${file_name}" "dmi_standard_load_${batch_name}_set.xml"; done
```

this is example from my gentoo box:

```
user@host ~/test $ ls -1
dmi_standard_load_B0001_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_B0002_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_B0003_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_B0004_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_B0005_set.xml
user@host ~/test $ for file_name in *; do echo -ne "Renaming file \"${file_name}\" Enter batch_name: "; read batch_name; mv "${file_name}" "dmi_standard_load_${batch_name}_set.xml"; done
Renaming file "dmi_standard_load_B0001_set.xml" Enter batch_name: test
Renaming file "dmi_standard_load_B0002_set.xml" Enter batch_name: another test
Renaming file "dmi_standard_load_B0003_set.xml" Enter batch_name: and test again
Renaming file "dmi_standard_load_B0004_set.xml" Enter batch_name: four
Renaming file "dmi_standard_load_B0005_set.xml" Enter batch_name: last, five
user@host ~/test $ ls -1
dmi_standard_load_and test again_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_another test_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_four_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_last, five_set.xml
dmi_standard_load_test_set.xml
user@host ~/test $
```